# How do I get to the Far Lands without my dual-core crashing?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I have the XYZ of the Far Lands , but my dual-core crashes there. I have the latest non-snapshot version (1.7.10) , but my dual-core crashes when I get there. Also , can the Far Lands be reached on superflat and in the End/Nether?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The [Far Lands](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Far_Lands) have not been in the game since Beta 1.8. The current world size is technically infinite, but according to the [wiki](https://minecraft.wiki/w/The_Overworld#Map_limitation), the player cannot walk past 30,000,000 in any direction. If you are playing in a current version of Minecraft and you teleport yourself further than that, I wouldn't be surprised if your game crashes. If you're not teleporting that far, I'm not sure why your game would crash.

In pre-Beta 1.8, the far lands occur in the Nether. The end simply has no land much past the main island so there would be no weird terrain generation that far out. The superflat world type [was not added till version 1.1 of Minecraft](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Superflat#History), so there is no way to have the far lands there.

Comment: Dont forget to mention that the far lands were a bug in the generation system. the system was just crashing (I dont remember for what specific reason other than having a really big coordinate number). Everyone who reached the far lands were experiencing a huge amount of lag and eventually, a crash. There is nothing to see in the far lands and nothing you can do.

Comment: Erm , I don't use 1.8. I use 1.7.2.

Comment: Beta 1.8 is not the same as the current minecraft version. Beta 1.8 was before the official release of Minecraft almost two years ago. They restarted the numbering at 1.0 then.

Comment: Beta 1.8 was when the far lands were removed. That's why kurtjmac of Far Lands or Bust plays in Beta 1.7.3.